# Filtering gridview with textbox and button using lists to fill gridview

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, list, gridview

I am currently busy creating a simple website. Files get copied on to my FTP server. On my web page is a Textbox,button and gridview.

Everything is working fine, when i load my website the gridview is not visible until you have search for something.At the moment i have no search code for my search button, i coded it to load every file into the grid view.

I now want to add some filtering when you click the search button, but i have no clue on how to do it and the Internet only shows how to do it with a database, but i am using New List object.

See my example code below. (This currently add all the files to the gridview)

```
 Dim filePaths() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/IIC/"))
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("FileName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("FilePath", GetType(String))
    dt.Rows.Clear()
    For Each filePath As String In filePaths
        dt.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath)
    Next

    If GridView2.Columns.Count > 2 Then
        For x = 2 To GridView2.Columns.Count - 1
            GridView2.Columns.RemoveAt(2)
        Next
    End If


    Dim FileNameCol As New BoundField
    Dim FilePathCol As New BoundField
    FileNameCol.DataField = "FileName"
    FileNameCol.HeaderText = "FileName"
    FilePathCol.DataField = "FilePath"
    FilePathCol.DataField = "FilePath"

    GridView2.Columns.Add(FileNameCol)
    GridView2.Columns.Add(FilePathCol)

    GridView2.DataSource = dt.Select("FileName LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'")
    GridView2.DataBind()
```

Any help showing me how to filter the gridview will help me a lot as i haven't really worked with lists before.

Note: The gridview does not use a Database

Designer Code for Gridview2

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" 
    EmptyDataText = "No files uploaded" Width="251px">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Text"  HeaderText="FileName" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text = "Download" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
```

Comment: How about using a `datatable`? You can do filters with `.Select()` like the `WHERE` parts in a database query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using a `DataTable`.

It has a `.Select()` function in which you can filter specific records inside the datatable (Like the `WHERE` part in a query but instead from a database, you are using it in a datatable)

Try this:

```
    Dim filePaths() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/IIC/"))
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("FileName", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("FilePath", GetType(String))
    dt.Rows.Clear()
    For Each filePath As String In filePaths
        dt.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath)
    Next

    If GridView2.Columns.Count > 1 Then
         For x = 1 To GridView2.Columns.Count - 1
             grdApproval.Columns.RemoveAt(1)
         Next
    End If


    Dim FileNameCol As New BoundField
    Dim FilePathCol As New BoundField
    FileNameCol.DataField = "FileName"
    FileNameCol.HeaderText = "FileName"
    FilePathCol.DataField = "FilePath"
    FilePathCol.HeaderText = "FilePath"

    GridView2.Columns.Add(FileNameCol)
    GridView2.Columns.Add(FilePathCol)

    GridView2.DataSource = dt.Select("FileName LIKE '%" & txtYourSearchBox.Text & "%'")
    GridView2.DataBind()
```

Comment: I get this error on Gridview2.Databind() 'A field or property with the name 'Text' was not found on the selected data source. My first column's name is File Name, the i have a download link in the next column which i coded already

Comment: Here is a link to my test site http://196.41.127.28/plesk-site-preview/www.oddydocs.co.za/196.41.127.28/

Comment: Site is published.I Stil get the error i got the first time.  
I get this error on Gridview2.Databind() 'A field or property with the name 'Text' was not found on the selected data source.....I ONLY GET AN ERROR WHEN THE SEARCH FIND SOMETHING

Comment: Still same error as before. Gridview2.Databind() 'A field or property with the name 'Text' was not found on the selected data source

Comment: You don't need this code anymore:  `<asp:BoundField DataField="Text"  HeaderText="FileName" />` then try my updated answer. It will now work for sure.

Comment: I Get this after i updated the code. 'A field or property with the name 'FileName' was not found on the selected data source.